# Exporting image from GEE to Google Cloud Bucket in PNG/JPEG format?

Tags: export, google-earth-engine, google-earth, png, jpg

The below lines of code shows the export of the image to the cloud. I am unable to convert my file to JPEG/PNG. I want my image to be saved in PNG/JPEG in the cloud.

```
    Export.image.toCloudStorage({
    image:  rgb.select(0,1,2),
    description: 'cog',
    bucket: 'sample_bucket',
    scale: 30,
    region:ft_bnd,
    fileFormat: 'png',
    formatOptions: {
    cloudOptimized: true
    },
    dimensions:256*256
    });
```

Comment: Does that code work but not do what you want? Does the documentation tell you you can do what you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't clear because you haven't specified what's not working, but you can't specify a scale + region and dimensions.  Those options are mutually exclusive.

Comment: I can't export the image in png /jpeg format . I wanted to know if Earth engine has provided any such faclity to export the image in cloud in jpeg or png format

Answer (score 2):

JPG or PNG are not supported for image export.

> You can export images from Earth Engine in GeoTIFF or TFRecord format.

As per the [GEE *Exporting Data* documentation](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/exporting).